# Chakra UI carousel - how to set more than 3 items per page in carousel

Tags: reactjs, next.js, chakra-ui

I  use this library:

```
https://github.com/Nazeeh21/Chakra-UI-Carousel
```

Here is example:

```
https://carousel-example.vercel.app/
```

Example code:

```
"use client";
import { Box, Flex } from "@chakra-ui/react";
import { Carousel, LeftButton, RightButton } from "chakra-ui-carousel";

const elements = [
  "Element 1",
  "Element 2",
  "Element 3",
  "Element 4",
  "Element 5",
  "Element 6",
  "Element 7",
  "Element 8",
  "Element 9",
  "Element 10",
];

export default function Home() {
  return (
    <Box p={2}>
      <Carousel gap={50}>
        {elements.map((element, index) => (
          <Box
            p={2}
            borderWidth={2}
            borderColor={"#ccc"}
            borderRadius={"0.5rem"}
            key={index}
            w="100%"
            h="100%"
          >
            {element}
          </Box>
        ))}
        
      </Carousel>
      <Flex w='full' justify='space-between' p={4}>
          <LeftButton />
          <RightButton />
        </Flex>
    </Box>
  );
}
```

This always in carousel display 3 items per page, there is no inforomation how to set example 7 items visible per page in carousel.

I try write own settings and pass but still display always 3 items per page.

```
const carouselOptions = {
    initialSlide: 0,
    slidesToScroll: 1,
    perPage: 6, // Adjust the number of visible slides
    infinite: true,
    spacing: 10, // Adjust the spacing between slides
    isRTL: false,
    isPlaying: false,
    interval: 5000,
    speed: 500,
  };

  return (
    <Box maxW="8xl" mx="auto" mt={12}>
      <Provider>
        <Carousel gap={10} options={carouselOptions}>{carouselItems}</Carousel>
        <LeftButton></LeftButton>
        <RightButton></RightButton>
      </Provider>
    </Box>
  );
};
```

Can anyone try help me analize this library and change settings to possible display more than 3 items per page ?

Comment: Based on the code [here](https://github.com/Nazeeh21/Chakra-UI-Carousel/blob/main/src/components/Carousel/index.tsx#L56) it looks like the library splits the page width in 3 and that's why you see 3 elements on your screen.

I think a better solution would be to develop your own `Carousel` component (similar to [this](https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/chakra-carousel-dd8vn?file=%2Fsrc%2FChakraCarousel.js) or [this](https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/chakra-ui-carousel-wgdp6?file=%2Fsrc%2FImageSlider.js%3A10%2C63)) and avoid hard-coupling of not so well-known libraries.

Comment: Otherwise, if you want to use an external library you should check for something more flexible and with more active users (eg [react-responsive-carousel](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-responsive-carousel) or [react-multi-carousel](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-multi-carousel))